# How to retrieve values from an object and store them in a $scope?

Tags: angularjs

After some help earlier with an array I'm Trying to retrieve `monthlyIncome`, `savePercent` and years values and store them in `$scope.monthlyIncome`, `$scope.savePercent` and `$scope.years`.

Where am I going wrong?

```
$scope.data2 = {
        "$id":"4157e8b1-efa2-4feb-bf75-e907c0e200e0",
        "$priority":null,
        "date":1457178818625,
        "email":"a@b.com",
        "firstname":"test",
        "lastname":"Isaacs",
        "monthly":328947,
        "monthlyIncome":1200,
        "regUser":"4157e8b1-efa2-4feb-bf75-e907c0e200e0",
        "savePercent":10,
        "years":40
    }; 

//for each object in data array
    angular.forEach(data2, function(value, key) {
      // check if value id is equals to 'monthlyIncome' OR 'savePercent' OR 'years'
      if (value == 'monthlyIncome' ||
          value == 'savePercent' || 
          value == 'years') {
        // add it's value with the same key (e.g. $scope.monthlyIncome)
        $scope.[value] = key;
      }
    });
```

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Why? You already have simple access to them using `data2` object. Doesn't make any sense creating primitives on `$scope` for those. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I agree with @charlietfl, but if you insist in do that, just remove the dot from this statement: `$scope.[value] = key;`

Comment: You are also confusing which part of object is key and which is value. Learning to use `console.log()` or breakpoints will help you see what different variables contain

Comment: Thanks guys... I can see the mistake now :)

Comment: and the easier way to pull the data!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need get better understanding [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) function.
In this case you should check not values, but keys:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('appController', function($scope, $log) {
      $scope.data2 = {
        "$id": "4157e8b1-efa2-4feb-bf75-e907c0e200e0",
        "$priority": null,
        "date": 1457178818625,
        "email": "a@b.com",
        "firstname": "test",
        "lastname": "Isaacs",
        "monthly": 328947,
        "monthlyIncome": 1200,
        "regUser": "4157e8b1-efa2-4feb-bf75-e907c0e200e0",
        "savePercent": 10,
        "years": 40
      };

      //for each key/value in data2
      angular.forEach($scope.data2, function(value, key) {
        // check if key is equals to 'monthlyIncome' OR 'savePercent' OR 'years'
        if (key == 'monthlyIncome' ||
            key == 'savePercent' ||
            key == 'years') {
          // add it's value with the same key (e.g. $scope.monthlyIncome)
          $scope[key] = value;
        }
      });

    });
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="appController">
    <ul>
      <li>{{monthlyIncome}}</li>
      <li>{{savePercent}}</li>
      <li>{{years}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I am trying hard to learn and sometimes overcomplicate things and mess them up! Thanks for you help again :)

Comment: @worc thanks for your vote ups. Feel free to ask, and good luck in learning. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you really need these values (be aware that you possibly copy primitives) and you already know which keys you need, why don't you assign them directly?

```
$scope.monthlyIncome = $scope.data2.monthlyIncome;
```

In most cases, I would prefer accessing them from the template via `data2.monthlyIncome` which also reflects the changes to primitive values in the originating object `data2`.

Comment: Thank you for your help this is a much easier way to do it! :)